# Modern 3D Animation Software

Tags: final-cut-pro, animation

Back in the day I used `Adobe Illustrator` to make a cross section of an item.  I then imported it into some other app that I could rotate that profile around its vertical axis, to get a shape.  I then exported that, and brought it into some animation software to spin it.  I use that video footage in `Final Cut Pro` and I have what I want.

How can I achieve that today?  I'm sure the apps have changed.  I'm unaware of what's available.  I don't want to overcomplicate this and keep it to a minimum.  Hopefully free software as well.

Cheers

Comment: This is such a broad questions and there are **many** tools all with a little different things in mind. Blender for example is open soure, free, widely used and cross-platform.

Comment: Blender is a render platform.  I can’t design 3D objects in Blender.

Comment: Tbh I am only editing videos and not doing any 3D work, but I always thought Blender can sort of do *anything*: https://www.blender.org/features/

Comment: Ah I've only seen rendering using network nodes.  I should take a look then at Blender.  I didn't know it had design features.